# How to disable kafka connection from spring boot test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-kafka

I am using spring kafka to consume message from kafka topic, so I have a kafka consumer configuration class:

```
@Configuration
class KafkaConfiguration {
 // kafka consumer configurations
}
```

I have some JUnit tests which will load spring context with mockMvc to test my API, I don't want to test features related to kafka messaging, how can I stop kafka from consuming message only for JUnit tests? It keep failing because I don't have a kafka server at my local and CI environment.

Spring profile is not a very good option, because I will have to write code like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!unit-test")
class KafkaConfiguration {
  //kafka configuration
}
```

which I will end up with production code written only for testing purpose, not very clean, is there other way I can do to disable kafka for tests?

Comment: As you had already isolated Kafka configuration in a dedicated configuration class, you may just have to configure your tests to use some specific configuration classes.
By using the annotation `ContextConfiguration`in your tests or by using the annotation `Import` in a test configuration class, you can choose which configuration you need to load.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation on configuration class

Example:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "kafka.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
```

, and add `application.properties` file property `kafka.enable=false`

Answer (score 0):

Spring Profiles have exactly this purpose. It always enabling/disabling parts of your application for various scenario's under which your application runs (staging, production, unit tests).

The only other option would be to make Kafka available during the test by using [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) for example.